# error with mvn exec:exec with alexa

Tags: java-8, ubuntu-14.04, alexa-voice-service

I am trying to work with alexa voice service app on ubuntu 14.04. I have installed Nodejs version 7.9.0 and JDK 8 version 1.8.0_131. I am successfully able to run the server, but getting error in running the command `mvn exec:exec`. `mvn validate` and `mvn install` build successfully, but still not able to start the client.

For java version 1.8.0_131, latest alpn-boot-version is not available. It is available latest for 1.8.0_121.

Is the error because of this mismatch?

```
    root@IM-RT-LP-017:/home/arajput/Downloads/p1/alexa/alexa-avs-sample-app/samples/javaclient# mvn exec:exec 
    [INFO] Scanning for projects...
    [INFO]                                                                         
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] Building Alexa Voice Service Sample Java Client 20160207.3
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] 
    [INFO] --- exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:exec (default-cli) @ sample-java-client ---
    #
    # A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
    #
    #  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007f6cc592e404, pid=9908, tid=0x00007f6c6c5b4700
    #
    # JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_131-b11) (build 1.8.0_131-b11)
    # Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.131-b11 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressed oops)
    # Problematic frame:
    # C  [libpthread.so.0+0xa404]  pthread_mutex_lock+0x4
    #
    # Core dump written. Default location: /home/arajput/Downloads/p1/alexa/alexa-avs-sample-app/samples/javaclient/core or core.9908
    #
    # An error report file with more information is saved as:
    # /home/arajput/Downloads/p1/alexa/alexa-avs-sample-app/samples/javaclient/hs_err_pid9908.log
    #
    # If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
    #   http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
    # The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
    # See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
    #
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] BUILD FAILURE
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] Total time: 2.807 s
    [INFO] Finished at: 2017-05-02T17:02:40+05:30
    [INFO] Final Memory: 11M/212M
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:exec (default-cli) on project sample-java-client: Command execution failed. Process exited with an error: 134 (Exit value: 134) -> [Help 1]
    [ERROR] 
    [ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
    [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
    [ERROR] 
    [ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
    [ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
    root@IM-RT-LP-017:/home/arajput/Downloads/p1/alexa/alexa-avs-sample-app/samples/javaclient#
```

Comment: can you show your pom file?

Answer (score 0):

```
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/6.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.amazon.alexa.avs</groupId>
  <artifactId>sample-java-client</artifactId>
  <version>20160207.3</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
  <name>Alexa Voice Service Sample Java Client</name>
  <url>https://developer.amazon.com/appsandservices/solutions/alexa/alexa-voice-service</url>

  <properties>
    <jetty.version>9.3.7.v20160115</jetty.version>
    <!-- The latest version of alpn-boot that supports JDK 1.8.0_121 -->
    <!-- To override, pass -Dalpn-boot.version=YOUR_VERSION when running "mvn install" and "mvn exec:exec" -->
    <!-- Your version can be determined here: http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/alpn-chapter.html#alpn-versions -->
    <alpn-boot.version>8.1.11.v20170118</alpn-boot.version>
    <slf4j.version>1.7.10</slf4j.version>
    <log4j.version>2.3</log4j.version>
  </properties>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
      <version>1.9</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
      <version>2.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
      <version>3.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
      <version>1.3.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>uk.co.caprica</groupId>
      <artifactId>vlcj</artifactId>
      <version>3.10.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
      <artifactId>javax.json</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javazoom</groupId>
      <artifactId>jlayer</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
          <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty.alpn</groupId>
      <artifactId>alpn-boot</artifactId>
      <version>${alpn-boot.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
      <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
      <version>1.9.13</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
      <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>log4j-slf4j-impl</artifactId>
      <version>${log4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
      <version>${log4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Jetty 9.3.7-SNAPSHOT -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
      <artifactId>jetty-alpn-client</artifactId>
      <version>${jetty.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
      <artifactId>jetty-http</artifactId>
      <version>${jetty.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty.http2</groupId>
      <artifactId>http2-client</artifactId>
      <version>${jetty.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty.http2</groupId>
      <artifactId>http2-http-client-transport</artifactId>
      <version>${jetty.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty.http2</groupId>
      <artifactId>http2-hpack</artifactId>
      <version>${jetty.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty.http2</groupId>
      <artifactId>http2-common</artifactId>
      <version>${jetty.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>

      <artifactId>jetty-server</artifactId>
      <version>${jetty.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
      <artifactId>jetty-security</artifactId>
      <version>${jetty.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
      <artifactId>jetty-servlet</artifactId>
      <version>${jetty.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
      <artifactId>jetty-util</artifactId>
      <version>${jetty.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
      <artifactId>jetty-io</artifactId>
      <version>${jetty.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
      <artifactId>jetty-client</artifactId>
      <version>${jetty.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
      <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
      <version>3.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>net.java.dev.jna</groupId>
      <artifactId>jna</artifactId>
      <version>4.2.2</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <resources>
      <resource>
        <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
        <filtering>true</filtering>
        <includes>
          <include>**/*.properties</include>
        </includes>
      </resource>
      <!-- Don't filter the mp3 files or they'll get corrupted -->
      <resource>
        <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
        <filtering>false</filtering>
        <includes>
          <include>**/*.mp3</include>
        </includes>
         </resource>
      <!-- Don't filter the png files or they'll get corrupted -->
      <resource>
        <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
        <filtering>false</filtering>
        <includes>
          <include>**/*.png</include>
        </includes>
      </resource>
    </resources>
    <pluginManagement>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.3</version>
          <configuration>
            <source>1.8</source>
            <target>1.8</target>
          </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
          <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>1.2.1</version>
          <configuration>
            <executable>java</executable>
            <arguments>
              <argument>-Xbootclasspath/p:${settings.localRepository}/org/mortbay/jetty/alpn/alpn-boot/${alpn-boot.version}/alpn-boot-${alpn-boot.version}.jar</argument>
              <argument>-Dlog4j.configurationFile=file:///${basedir}/log4j2.xml</argument>
              <argument>-classpath</argument>
              <classpath/>
              <argument>-Djna.library.path=${env.VLC_PATH}</argument>
              <argument>com.amazon.alexa.avs.App</argument>
            </arguments>
          </configuration>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
  </build>
</project>
```

Comment: here is pom.xml in  ../alexa-avs-sample-app/samples/javaclient